# How to add a user in Cognito User Pool group?

Tags: python, aws-lambda, amazon-cognito

Just started with Cognito User Pools. I am using the Python lambda function and boto3 to create users with the required fields.
Now, I want to add users in a particular group using lambda. How to do the same?
I created a group 'superadmin' in Cognito and using the below API.

```
response = client.admin_add_user_to_group(
    UserPoolId='user_pool_id',
    Username='testuser',
    GroupName='superadmin'
)
```

but I am getting the obvious error, NotAuthorizedException. How to pass developer credentials here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you are using a lambda, the best practice would be to create a policy that allows you to add user to group and attach this policy to your lambda role. You do not need to pass developer credentials in a lambda as default lambda "credentials" are passed to your boto3 client for every call.